# contar palabras linea por linea en java

Tags: java

Hola quisiera su apoyo ya que estoy realizando mi programa de contador de palabras y lo que me solicitan que tenga en salida lo siguiente:

### EJEMPLO DE DATOS DE SALIDA

```
Dos palabras en la linea 1
dos palabras en la linea 2
una palabra en la linea 3
total de palabras 5
Espacios = 2
```

codigo:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Alfabeto {
    
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("------------------------");
        System.out.println("------------------------");
        Scanner in  = new Scanner(System.in);
        String textoEntrada;
        String[] vocales = {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u"};
        int cantVocales = 0;

        System.out.println("Introduce un texto de entrada");
        textoEntrada = in.nextLine();

        String letraMasRepetida = "";
        int cantidadRepetida = 0;
        int cantPalabras = textoEntrada.trim().split(" ").length;
        System.out.println("Hay " + cantPalabras + " palabras");

       
        List<String> textoList = Arrays.asList(textoEntrada.split(""));

   
        for (String v : vocales){
            cantVocales += Collections.frequency(textoList, v);
        }        
        System.out.println("Hay " + cantVocales + " vocales");
        
        
        for(String item : textoList){
            
            int cantidad = Collections.frequency(textoList, item);
           
            if(cantidadRepetida < cantidad && !item.equals(" ")){
                letraMasRepetida = item;
                cantidadRepetida = cantidad;
            }
            System.out.println("La letra " + item + " se repite  " + cantidad);
        }
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(String.format("La letra %s es la que mayor se repite, con %o veces", letraMasRepetida, cantidadRepetida));
    }
    
}
```

//EJEMPLO DE DATOS DE SALIDA
Dos palabras en la linea 1
dos palabras en la linea 2
una palabra en la linea 3
total de palabras 5
Espacios = 2

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y escribe cuál es el problema _específico_ en cuestión. Por cierto, ¡NO ES NECESARIO QUE GRITES! Lee [ask].

Comment: y el ejemplo de entrada??

Comment: Datos de entrada.                          El carpintero
vuela, vuela
feliz


Salida al usuario:
e = 4
l = 4
, = 1.....

Dos palabras en la linea 1
dos palabras en la linea 2
una palabra en la linea 3
total de palabras 5
Espacios = 2

Answer (score 1):

Podrías aplicar un bucle `do while` para ingresar linea por linea y a su vez guardar cada linea en un `List` con el cual podes trabajar en lo demás

```
System.out.println("------------------------");
System.out.println("------------------------");
Scanner in  = new Scanner(System.in);
String textoEntrada;
//Declaramos list donde guardaremos las lineas    
List<String>lista=new ArrayList<>();
System.out.println("Introduce un texto de entrada un enter para ingresar linea 2 enter para terminar ");

 do{
    textoEntrada=in.nextLine();
//si ingresamos una linea vacia no lo guardamos en el List
    if (!textoEntrada.equals("")) {
        lista.add(textoEntrada); 
    }
//mientras no ingresemos una linea vacia podremos ingresar mas lineas de texto
    }while (!textoEntrada.equals(""));      
            
    System.out.println("\nResumen de lineas\n");
    aplicamos split a cada linea para conseguir la cantidad de palabras
    lista.forEach(p->System.out.println(p.trim().split(" ").length+" palabra en linea:"+(lista.indexOf(p)+1)+"\n"));
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]